# Повтор данных в модалке VueJs

Tags: html, vue.js

Не понимаю как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку открытия модалки, к примеру, второго объекта, открывалась модалка с данными этого же объекта.
https://codepen.io/Glebmak/pen/wvBgeVG

```js
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data () {
  return {
   showModal: false,
   cands: [
    { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'},
        { firstName: 'Flow', lastName: 'Obama'},
        { firstName: 'Kanye', lastName: 'West'}
   ],
  }
 },
})
```

```css
#app {
  font-family: Open Sans;
}
section {
  max-width: 920px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.title {
  text-align: center;
}
.candidates {
  margin: 0 auto;
  tbody {
    tr {
      td {
        padding-right: 16px;
        img {
          width: 50px;
          border-radius: 50%;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9998;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.modal {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 9999;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <section>
    <table class="candidates">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Surname</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(cand, index) in cands" :key="index">
          <td>{{ cand.firstName }}</td>
          <td>{{ cand.lastName }}</td>
          <td><button @click="showModal = true">View</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="overlay" v-if="showModal" @click="showModal = false"></div>
    <div class="modal" v-if="showModal">
      <div class="modal-contant" v-for="(cand, index) in cands" :key="index">
        <img src="" alt="" />
        <div>{{ cand.firstName }}</div>
        <div>{{ cand.lastName }}</div>
      </div>
      <button class="close" @click="showModal = false">Close</button>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно вынести обработку клика в отдельный метод и в нем работать с данными

```js
    new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     data () {
      return {
       showModal: false,
       cands: [
        { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'},
            { firstName: 'Flow', lastName: 'Obama'},
            { firstName: 'Kanye', lastName: 'West'},
{ firstName: 'Ozzy', lastName: 'Ozborne'},
       ],
                dataForModal: {},
      }
     },
    methods: {
      openModal(cand){
          this.dataForModal = cand;
          this.showModal = true;
      }
    }
    })
```

```css
#app {
  font-family: Open Sans;
}
section {
  max-width: 920px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.title {
  text-align: center;
}
.candidates {
  margin: 0 auto;
  tbody {
    tr {
      td {
        padding-right: 16px;
        img {
          width: 50px;
          border-radius: 50%;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9998;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.modal {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 9999;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <section>
    <table class="candidates">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Surname</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <template v-for="(cand, index) in cands">
        <tr v-if="(index+1) % 2 === 0" :key="index">
          <td>{{ cand.firstName }}</td>
          <td>{{ cand.lastName }}</td>
          <td><button @click="openModal(cand)">View</button></td>
        </tr>
       </template>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="overlay" v-if="showModal" @click="showModal = false"></div>
    <div class="modal" v-if="showModal">
      <div class="modal-contant">
        <img src="" alt="" />
        <div>{{ dataForModal.firstName }}</div>
        <div>{{ dataForModal.lastName }}</div>
      </div>
      <button class="close" @click="showModal = false">Close</button>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

> А еще есть такой вопрос, если у нас у объектов будут айдишники
>   (1,2,3,4 ...), то как сделать, чтобы отображались только четные
>   айдишники?

Нужно обернуть отображаемую часть в обертку, обычно это делают с помощью тега `template`, и отображать ее по условию

Comment: Спасибо, А еще есть такой вопрос, если у нас у объектов будут айдишники (1,2,3,4 ...), то как сделать, чтобы отображались только четные айдишники?